# Root directory mount in a weird location

Tags: mount, root, drive

I recently installed ubuntu on a new computer (I had it with me on an old laptop before). Usually I would follow some guide to install Ubuntu and assign the correct home folders, swap folders. Now I decided to save time and install Ubuntu with the dual boot option without configuring anything at all (not custom option).

[image: Picture 1]

Every time I navigate around the root I have to type in the long drive name. Renaming doesn't work since it says it's being used

[image: Picture 2 - renaming]

So is there anyway to work this around? Making my life easier or I have to spend time typing?

EDIT:
Here is the picture of sudo mount
[image: sudo mount]
What I tried to do was to access **plymouth** folder. 
**ls** command also doesn't show **plymouth**
[image: plymouth]

Comment: It should still be mounted under '/', I think you're just getting confused with the drive UUID. Can you update your answer with the output from `sudo mount` which should list all your current drives and mount points

Comment: Yeah I edited it. Hope it is more clear